# Check whether the first character is a space

Tags: jquery, validation, input, textfield

How can I check if the first character of the input field is an empty space or not with jQuery? I would need to check so that users can't enter a username like " rreea". Empty spaces *after* the first character are allowed. For example, "his name" is okay, but " his name" or " hisname" are not accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `myString.substring(0,1)` or `myString[0]` to get the first character.

You can *trim* the input; this doesn't check whether or not it starts with a space, it makes such a check redundant and gives you usable input regardless of whether or not the original string had an initial space.

You could also match the string for `/^\s/` which means an initial whitespace, or `/^\s+/` meaning any number of initial whitespace.

Answer (score 8):

In spite of checking just add string trimming using [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method. It removes all spaces from left and right edges of the string.

```
var value = $.trim($("input").val());
```

Otherwise, you can use

```
$("input").val().substring(0, 1)
```

to get the first character safely.

Comment: Trim does not check if only the first char is empty

Comment: @FrançoisWahl that's true, but it makes checking for a leading space redundant.

Comment: I thought OP explicitly asked for a check on the first char being an empty space...

Comment: Ya, this solution trims it without actually rejecting it which is what the requirement is `for example "his name" is ok. Only " his name" or " hisname" are not accepted.`

Comment: I'm with Rory and VisioN here. It might very well be that trim is exactly what OP was attempting to achieve, only not being aware that there was such a function. As long as it's pointed out that it does what it does, and not explicitly what's asked, I think this may well be what OP ends up accepting. As an analogy: if a user asks what the maximum numbers of columns you can have in a database table is, the best answer is often (perhaps not always) not a number, but an indication that there's something wrong with the database design.

Comment: Originally the "Otherwise, you can use..." was not part of the answer when I read it so now that it is in it I think the answer is showing a solution to the exact question but also a propably better way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can acces chars in a string like an array. So the following should work:

```
if ($('#your-input').val()[0] === " ") {
    // error
}
```

But what if there are two spaces? I think you should check against a trimmed copy of your value…

```
var value = $('#your-input').val();
if (value.trim() !== value) {
    // error
}
```

The `trim()` method comes with *Javascript 1.8.1*. If you want to support earlier versions you can also your `$.trim(value)`. Hope this helps.